# iOS create boolean parameter based on values of Core Data parameters

Tags: ios, core-data, getter-setter

First apologies for the n00b question...

I have a Core Data object "Tile" with a corresponding generated NSManagedObject class.
It has 2 parameters which come from the database
- beingPlayed
- position

Now, I want to create an instance boolean parameter isOnBoard which is based on the value of these 2 CoreData values.

Tile.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *isInPot;
```

Tile.m:

```
@implementation Tile

@dynamic beingPlayed;
@dynamic position;


-(BOOL *)isInPot
{

   if (beingPlayed == 0 and position == 0) return TRUE;
   else return FALSE;
}
```

But when I want to use the dynamic parameters I can not access them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `self. beingPlayed` and `self. position`. ie if (self.beingPlayed == 0 && self.position == 0) return YES;
   else return NO;

Comment: As others have hinted at, you should not use TRUE/FALSE in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use * with BOOL.

Tile.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isInPot;
```

Tile.m:

```
@implementation Tile

@dynamic beingPlayed;
@dynamic position;


-(BOOL)isInPot
{

   return (self.beingPlayed == 0 && self.position == 0);
}
```

Comment: Your code could be only : `return (self.beingPlayed == 0 && self.position == 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
-(BOOL)isInPot
{
   return (self.beingPlayed == 0 && self.position == 0);
}
```

Comment: Your code could be only : `return (self.beingPlayed == 0 && self.position == 0);`